# greaterThan query throws unexpected AST node near >

Tags: java, jpa, jpql, criteria-api

I'm trying to write a Predicate in which only objects of the class Employee are returned when they have more than 1 Manager. It should return `true` when there are more than 1 managers for this employee, and `false` if there are 0 or 1. The total result should be asserted against a boolean which indicates the filter option the user has selected, but to keep things simple, I've replaced the variable in the last line with the hardcoded value `true`. The code looks like this:

```
public Predicate toPredicate(final Root<Employee> employeeRoot, final CriteriaQuery<?> query, final CriteriaBuilder cb) {
    final Subquery<Long> subquery = query.subquery(Long.class);
    final Root<EmployeeManager> employeeManagerRoot = subquery.from(EmployeeManager.class);
    subquery.select(cb.count(employeeManagerRoot));
    subquery.where(cb.equal(employeeManagerRoot.get("employee"), employeeRoot.<Long> get("id")));

    return cb.equal(cb.greaterThan(subquery, Long.valueOf(1)), true);
}
```

However, the following error is produced when trying to run this code:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException:
>   unexpected AST node: > near line 1, column 453 [select generatedAlias0
>   from com.test.domain.core.entities.Employee as generatedAlias0 where (
>   generatedAlias0.id in (select generatedAlias1.employee.id from
>   com.test.domain.core.entities.EmployeeManager as generatedAlias1 where
>   generatedAlias1.manager=1L) ) and ( (select count(generatedAlias2)
>   from com.test.domain.core.entities.EmployeeManager as generatedAlias2
>   where generatedAlias2.employee=generatedAlias0.id)>1L=:param0 )

I've tried to run the SQL which was outputted in the exception directly into the database, and it seems to be returning the correct values! However, as you can see, I'm trying to confirm whenever or not the `greaterThan` function equals to `true`. As you can see in the exception message, this `true` is replaced by `:param0`.

So what is going wrong in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was in the last line. There is no need to check if the greaterThan function equals to true or not.

```
return cb.equal(cb.greaterThan(subquery, Long.valueOf(1)), true);
```

changes to

```
return cb.greaterThan(subquery, Long.valueOf(1));
```

The reason I messed this one up is because the function in my application also has a variable indicating whenever or not `true` or `false` is wanted. I made an if-else statement so I return `cb.greaterThan` or `cb.lessThanOrEqualTo` depending on this variable.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't need a subquery, just a GROUP BY - HAVING statement like follows. Tested with EclipseLink:

```
CriteriaQuery<Tuple> cq = cb.createTupleQuery();
Root<Employee> root = cq.from(Employee.class);
Join<Employee, Manager> managers = root.join("managers");
Expression<Long> countManagers = cb.count(managers);
cq.multiselect(root, countManagers);
cq.groupBy(root);
cq.having(cb.greaterThan(countManagers, Long.valueOf(1)));
List<Tuple> result = em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
for (Tuple t : result) {
    Employee emp = (Employee) t.get(0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I'm not able to create a Predicate which returns true or false whenever the count is greater than 1 or not. Like defined in the question, my SQL query seems to be correct.

Comment: It's difficult to say whether your query is correct or not, since it throws the exception. And the Criteria API javadoc is quite vague about the correct usage of subquery. I suggest you to start with my something working, and my solution does work indeed, and produces an SQL query that does exactly the thing you need.